# How to make a random number a multiple of 16 in Python?

Tags: python, random, numbers

I am trying to make a random multiple of 16 between 32 and 160 in Python using the 'random' library. Can anyone help me with this? Here is the code:

```
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,208))
pygame.display.set_caption("TinyRacer")
car = pygame.image.load("car.png")
car2 = pygame.image.load("car2.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
run = True
y = 64
e_y = random.randint(32,160)
e_x = 0

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_UP] and y > 32:
      y -= 16
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 160:
      y += 16
    e_x = e_x - 18
    if e_x < 0:
      e_x = 300
      e_y = random.randint(32,160)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(car, (0,y))
    screen.blit(car2, (e_x,e_y))
    screen.blit(bg,(0,0))   
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(16) 
    
pygame.quit()
```

I cannot seem to find anything on this topic.

Comment: Generate a number between 2 and 10 (inclusive) and multiply it by 16.

Answer (score 1):

The following generates a random multiple of 16 in [2 * 16, 10 * 16] = [32, 160]:

```
from random import randint

my_number = randint(2, 10) * 16
print(my_number)
```

Alternatively (and probably better), achieve the same effect by using

```
randrange(32, 160 + 1, 16)
```

`randint(a, b)` returns a random integer in the closed interval [a, b] and is an alias for `randrange(a, b + 1)`.

`randrange(a, b[, c])` returns a randomly selected element from `range(a, b[, c])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to achieve that. You could make the following function that generates an ordinary random integer, from which an offset is made up and subtracted. Offset here means the distance from a multiple of 16.

```
import random

def rand16():
    foo = random.randint(32, 175) # up to 175 to make equal distribution. just under the first unwanted multiple of 16 in the high numbers range.
    over = foo % 16 # how much over a multiple of 16 is foo?
    mult_of_16 = foo - over # calculating a multiple of 16 by subtracting the offset
    return mult_of_16
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
random.randrange(32,160,16)
```